# Eviar parámetros y arreglos por método post con JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Intento pasar una serie de parámetros y arreglos por el método post con JQuery de un archivo a otro, pero no funciona. Estoy haciéndolo de la siguiente manera.

```
var datos_contrato = ["1","2"];
$.post("<?=Zend_Registry::get('base_action')?>insert.php", {
            pos: a_pos, cre: a_cre, cep: a_cep, 'ddc': datos_contrato
......
```

Comment: te faltó una coma antes de 'ddc', mira:
 
pos: a_pos, cre: a_cre, cep: a_cep, 'ddc': datos_contrato

Comment: Si la tenia, solo que aquí se me fue ponerla, aún así no funciona.

Comment: Asumiendo que las variables a_pos, a_cre y a_cep están definidas, lo probé y me funcionó perfectamente.